# Given thread does not exist when executing a runnable in a threadpool

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I've the following problem with an app:
In order to perform some actions in background I declare a ThreadPoolExecutor

```
private static ThreadPoolExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 100,
         100, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
```

And then I run the task making

```
poolExecutor.execute (new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Process.getThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
             ...
        }
```

But the app crashes at that point saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given thread does not exist
```

Whats the problem with the code? Thanks

Comment: I think the `getThreadPriority` method expects a thread ID as param and you give a thread priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean `setThreadPriority` instead of `getThreadPriority`

```
poolExecutor.execute (new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
         ...
    }
```